# How to bind two different attributes to two different datacontexts WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, menu

I have a standard menu where the headers are bound to a list in one viewmodel, and i want to bind the command from another viewmodel. I want this to be able to change language in the application. I defined the menu like this:

```
<Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top" DataContext="{Binding MenuViewModel, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource mainViewModel}}">
```

where MenuViewModel contains all the commands and another viewmodel called LanguageViewModel contains all the headers. I then have to define every MenuItem like this:

```
            <MenuItem Command="{Binding Path=NewProjectCommand}">
                <MenuItem.Header>
                    <Label DataContext="{StaticResource languageViewModel}" Content="{Binding Path=Names[menu.project.addnode]}" />
                </MenuItem.Header>
            </MenuItem>
```

Which means at least 5 lines of code just for one MenuItem, and the menu might contain over 30 MenuItems...
Is there any simpler way to do this? I was thinking about templates but don't know how i would do that.

Comment: What is `menu.project.addnode`? If you're doing localization this way, I think it might be easier in the end to use `DynamicResource` with locale specific resources. But if you've got some time in this approach, another option might be to have a global static languageviewmodel instance, and just pass a n x:Static key to a ValueConverter which would return the appropriate value from the languageviewmodel. Or even easier, give every regular viewmodel a reference to that static languageviewmodel, so you can work from the same DataContext.

Comment: You can make attached behavior to set Header for `MenuItem`. Will looks like this  in xaml: `<MenuItem Command="..." local:MenuHeader="menu.project.addnode" />`.

Comment: I'm using a file with all the <key, value> strings for the every language, and menu.peoject.addnode is one of the keys. Then I parse the file and put all the key value pairs in a Dictionary. I want to be able to add languages to the application dynamically and this was the best way I thought. Is there a standard way of implementing localization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `menu.project.addnode` is a string key, the following works for me:

```
<MenuItem 
    Command="{Binding NewProjectCommand}"
    Header="{Binding Names[menu.project.addnode], Source={StaticResource languageViewModel}"
    />
```

Here's the quickie test VM I used for the localization strings:

```
public class LanguageViewModel
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> Names { get; } = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "menu.project.addnode", "Add New Node" }
    };
}
```

Comment: Aaah that's what I'm looking for! Very helpful.